# can't execute python code when running jupyter notebook on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook on an ubuntu server. I am able to access the web UI, but when I try to run a command, all I get is a [*]. Nothing will execute, even just a print function.

[Attempting to print the word "dog" in console, to no avail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKVig.jpg)

It seems like maybe the console is not able to communicate with the kernel, so maybe it's a network issue. If you have any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks and let me know if more info would be helpful!

Comment: do you mean that you are logged in host A and the notebook server is running on host B?  if your answer is yes, what do you want to do on the remote machine, without authenticating yourself? `import os; os.remove(...)` ???

Comment: I am logged onto a machine that is also running the notebook server. Changing the port from 8888 to 8889 fixed the problem for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to run python code by changing the port from 8888 to 8889. It appears that the kernel could not stay connected at port 8888. In the web UI, the Console showed these messages constantly:

```
Kernel: kernel_connected (c57dbcda-cf7a-4af4-80bf-26424826d533)
kernel.js:100 Kernel: kernel_disconnected (c57dbcda-cf7a-4af4-80bf-26424826d533)
kernel.js:551 Connection lost, reconnecting in 1 seconds.
```

I'm not sure why the default port didn't work but changing it has solved the problem.